# Rename a table in the controller by query

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I try to do a private message application with an user_id who send the message and a post_id who receive the message in the table.

I did the association on my table like this:

```
$this->belongsTo('receiver', [
            'className' => 'Users',
            'foreignKey' => 'post_id'
        ]);
$this->belongsTo('shipper', [
            'className' => 'Users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
            ]);
```

But now I need to merge these to get one 'interlocutor' in my request:

```
$messages = $this->Messages->find()->where(['post_id =' => $id])
->orWhere(['user_id =' => $id])->contain(['shipper','receiver']);
```

I know I have to filter with function in the contain to get only the shipper or the receiver who's not me but I don't know how to **merge or simply rename** 'shipper' and 'receiver' into 'interlocutor'.

All I did is working, btw.
I'm not that good in english so if you have a better title, let me know it

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods

Example:

```
public function findInterlocutor(Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query->contain(['shipper','receiver']);
    return $query;
}
```

Calling it this way:

```
$messages = $this->Messages->find()->where(['post_id =' => $id])
->orWhere(['user_id =' => $id])->find('interlocutor');
```

Please let me know if it works...

Comment: it doesn't work, that just move the contain into a custom finder, the result is the same

Comment: It works according to your post: 
*rename 'shipper' and 'receiver' into 'interlocutor'.*